# Разница между VARCHAR и VARCHAR2

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Все кто имел дело с БД *Oracle*, знают, что объявлять символьные поля и переменные надо как  `VARCHAR2`, а не `VARCHAR`.

Но эти типы данных вроде синонимы:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id number,
  text VARCHAR(10),
  text2 VARCHAR2(10)
);

Name  Null Type
----- ---- ------------
ID         NUMBER
TEXT       VARCHAR2(10)
TEXT2      VARCHAR2(10)
```

Так какая все таки между ними разница?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171196/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-varchar2-in-oracle

Comment: @Dmitry  Спасибо! Я тоже этот линк нашел.

Comment: @0xdb Да, я знаю, но давать ответ пока не планировал.

Comment: Никакой разницы. А придумали чтобы было что спрашивать на собеседованиях.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На данный момент они синонимы.

`VARCHAR` зарезервирован `Oracle` для поддержки, *в будущем*, различия между `NULL` и пустой строкой, как описано в стандарте `ANSI`.

`VARCHAR2` не делает различий между `NULL` и пустой строкой, и никогда не будет делать.

Если вы полагаетесь на то, что пустая строка и `NULL` - одно и то же, используйте `VARCHAR2`.

<sub>перевод ответа [@Quassnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1171200/2881286)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

В настоящее время, никакой разницы. Тип `VARCHAR` является псевдонимом `VARCHAR2` и будет  при объявлении заменён на `VARCHAR2`.

`VARCHAR` зарезервирован для использования в будущих релизах для соответствия стандарту ANSI/ISO-SQL и *Oracle* не рекомендует этот тип к применению. Поэтому, все пользуются типом `VARCHAR2` потому, что его поведение никогда не изменится.

В чём отличие `VARCHAR2` от стандарта, их два:

- пустая строка интерпретируется как `NULL` с длиной `NULL` (не 0)
- `NULL` при конкантинации строк игнорируется, в стандарте результатом такой конкантинации будет `NULL`

Почему так вышло (сокращённо перефразирую[@JustinCave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203493/why-does-oracle-9i-treat-an-empty-string-as-null/203536#203536)):

*Oracle* очень старый производитель на рынке БД. Во времена, когда ещё SQL не был стандартизирован, теоретики *Oracle* приняли дизайнерское решение, что пустая строка в полях БД не содержит информации и по сути есть `NULL`.
Со временем, когда появился стандарт SQL и было решено, что `NULL` и пустая строка по сущности различны, уже было много пользователей со старым кодом, который эту разницу не учитывал. Так *Oracle* был поставлен перед выбором, делать существующий код не действительным или нарушать стандарт SQL. Был принято, по мнению *Oracle*, менее деструктивное решение, зарезервировать тип данных `VARCHAR` для изменения и соответствия стандарту SQL и введению нового типа данных `VARCHAR2`, неизменность поведения которого гарантируется.

Когда будут произведены намеченые изменения в поведении `VARCHAR`?

Так было [в версии 7](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/dcommon/oin/index.htm), заметьте фразу - "в следующей версии Oracle7":

> The VARCHAR datatype is currently synonymous with the VARCHAR2 datatype. It is recommended that you use VARCHAR2 rather than VARCHAR. In a future version of Oracle7, VARCHAR might be a separate datatype used for variable length character strings compared with different comparison semantics.

И, более чем 20 лет спустя, в [релизе 19c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-DF7E10FC-A461-4325-A295-3FD4D150809E):

> Do not use the VARCHAR data type. Use the VARCHAR2 data type instead. Although the VARCHAR data type is currently synonymous with VARCHAR2, the VARCHAR data type is scheduled to be redefined as a separate data type used for variable-length character strings compared with different comparison semantics.

Comment: Псевдоним,  а не синоним - это верно?

Comment: @simpleCode В документации синоним, но мне более импонирует псевдоним (_alias_) .  Даже в примере в вопросе видно, что тип VARCHAR будет замешён и в data dictionary сохраняется VARCHAR2.

Comment: `И, более чем 20 лет спустя, в последнем релизе 18c:` - это интересно! :)

Comment: @MaxU Я года неправильно посчитал?

Comment: @0xdb, нет, просто этот интересный факт прошел мимо меня...

Answer (score -2):

Правильный ответ: для использования они не отличаются, при хранении VARCHAR2 не резервирует место под значения NULL, в отличии от VARCHAR, т.е. для хранения (для админов это важно). ответ в https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171196/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-varchar2-in-oracle не корректен. Никаких отличий работы с NULL для VARCHAR или VARCHAR2 нет (в будущем может появиться разница между  VARCHAR и VARCHAR2, а сейчас ее действительно нет). Ниже пример иллюстрирует одинаковое поведение:

```
DECLARE
  l_str VARCHAR(10):='';
  l_STR2 VARCHAR2(10) :='';
BEGIN
    IF l_str IS NULL THEN 
         dbms_output.put_line('l_str is null'); 
        ELSE
         dbms_output.put_line('l_str is not null'); 
    END IF; 

    IF l_str2 IS NULL THEN 
         dbms_output.put_line('l_str2 is null'); 
        ELSE
         dbms_output.put_line('l_str2 is not null');    
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: ссылка на "правильный" ответ, ведет на перевод ответов из второй ссылки

Comment: Если вы принимаете правку от анонимных участников, пожалуйста проверяйте ее. Правка не исправила ваш ответ и была по сути безсмысленна.