# Разница в количестве возвращаемых строк при явной и неявной группировке на пустой таблице

Tags: sql, oracle, ansi, oracle18c

Ни для кого не секрет, что агрегатная функция на пустой таблице, например:

```
create table t1 (id number);

select count (1) from t1;
```

вернёт вернёт одну строчку:

```
  COUNT(1)
----------
         0
```

Как известно, здесь будет произведена неявная групировка с объединением всех записей в одну общую группу. Согласно стандарту SQL, даже если результат такой группировки не содержит ни одной строчки, он будет преобразован в одну строчку. Поэтому, результат запроса выше объясним и широко известен.

Но можно задать глобальную группировку, т.е. без указания полей для группировки, явно:

```
select count (1) from t1 group by ();
```

и результат не совсем ожидаемый:

> no rows selected

Почему при явной группировке результат отличается?

Comment: «Как известно, здесь будет произведена неявная групировка ...» Можете добавить ссылку на это поведение если не сложно? Не совсем ясно что именно имеется ввиду.

Comment: @defaultlocale Рад бы, но в документации об этом явно не упомянуто. А что конкретно не ясно? Что все записи группируются в одну?

Comment: Неясно обязательно ли это называть неявной группировкой. И допустимо ли говорить, что `COUNT` без `GROUP BY` возвращает число всех строк без группировки (в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Aggregate-Functions.html#GUID-62BE676B-AF18-4E63-BD14-25206FEA0848) написано примерно так). В [комментариях к другому посту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/989173#comment1670080_989213) Вы написали, что второй вариант неточен вот я и задумался. Прошу прощения, что придираюсь к словам :)

Comment: Спасибо за конструктивные предложения. А как это поведение лучше назвать? Группировка производится (как ещё назвать трансформацию N строк в одну), и если group by явно не задан, то как ещё назвать такое поедение, кроме как неявное. Или? В ссылке, которую вы привели (2-й абзац), об этом скупо упомяното. Но, в этой теме камень - почему вернёт одну строку, даже если в группе нет ни одной, а об этом нигде в доке не говорится. Поэтому я и не влючил ссылку на офф. док.

Comment: Как по мне, так оба варианта допустимы. Можно сказать, что `COUNT` без `GROUP BY` — особый случай, который считает число всех строк. При этом можно уточнить, что если строк нет, то вернется одно значение 0, а можно и не уточнять (в доках не уточняют, насколько я понял). Также можно сказать, что `COUNT` без `GROUP BY` выполняет неявную группировку всех строк в одну группу без проверки на уникальность. Единственное что меня напрягает так это то, что «группировку» я воспринимаю как «группировка по всем полям», но это субъективная оценка.

Comment: Хорошо, я ешё раз обдумаю формулировки. 1) "COUNT без GROUP BY" - не совсем так, это касается всех аггрегатных функций. 2) "Единственное что меня напрягает так это то, что «группировку» я воспринимаю как «группировка по всем полям»" - если вы посмотрите историю правок, то заметите, что у меня почему-то проскочило такое же восприятие. Выкинул как "заблуждение". Такую группировку (global grouping как часто можно встретить), всё таки лучше назвать - "группировка без указания полей",  т.е. по всем записям в resultset.

Answer (score 6):

Возможность явной группировки без указания полей `group by ()` была введена в стандарте *SQL:1999* совместно с введением *Grouping Sets*. Реализована она была в версии 9iR1 в 2001 году.

С тех пор, включая 12c, реализация была выполнена с отличающимся поведением при явной и неявной группировке.

В актуальном стандарте *SQL:2016-2* явно указано, что должна выполнятся синтаксическая трансформация с добавлением `group by ()`, где требуется глобальная группировка, но `group by` явно не задан.

В релизе 18c *Oracle*, без какого-либо упоминания в списке изменений или документации, изменил поведение явной глобальной групировки:

```
18c> select count (1) from t1 group by ();

  COUNT(1)
----------
         0
```

PS Вероятно, это можно разценить как желание более полного соответствия стандартам. Есть надежда, что дойдёт очередь и до других отклонений от стандарта, таких как - [*пустая строка интерпретируется как NULL*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/805114/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-varchar-%d0%b8-varchar2).