# Как в oracle в функции count вернуть ноль, если нет данных?

Tags: база-данных, oracle, null, group-by

Вот мой код:

```
SELECT count(s.sid) 
FROM (  SELECT name, sd1.sid 
        FROM subscribers s1, subscribers_dogovorov sd1
        WHERE s1.sid = sd1.sid 
          and data_finish > SYSDATE
        GROUP BY name, sd1.sid
        HAVING count(sd1.sid)>1
      ) x1,
     (  SELECT s2.sid, sale_dat 
        FROM subscribers s2, salemap sp2
        WHERE s2.sid = sp2.sid 
          and sale_dat < SYSDATE 
          and ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sale_dat, SYSDATE), 0) BETWEEN 0 and 2
        GROUP BY s2.sid, sale_dat
      ) x2, 
     subscribers s
WHERE x2.sid = x1.sid 
  and s.sid = x2.sid
GROUP BY s.sid;
```

Тут у меня oracle возвращает такой ответ:

```
no data found
```

То есть в таблице нет данных, удовлетворяющих условиям в запросе. Именно поэтому мне в count(s.sid) нужно вернуть цифру 0. Как это сделать?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь результат этого запроса получить в переменную? Покажите как запрос используется в функции.

Comment: count - вернет 0, если нет данных

Comment: *oracle возвращает такой ответ* live.oracle.com в подобных случаях возвращает ноль - и ему я верю больше.

Comment: @faksel Не всегда. См. мой ответ ниже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно убрать `GROUP BY`, как бы парадоксально это ни звучало. С `GROUP BY`:

```
select count(*)
  from (select 1 a, 2 b from dual)
 where b > 10
 group by a;

no rows selected
```

Без `GROUP BY`:

```
select count(*)
  from (select 1 a, 2 b from dual)
 where b > 10;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

Объясняется просто: в случае с группировкой СУБД пытается сгруппировать данные, а так как строк нет, то и группировать нечего, и на выходе имеем `No data found`. А без группировки просто возвращается число строк.

Comment: Небольшая неточность в формулировке - "А без группировки просто возвращается ...". Группировка всё таки останется, вы наверно хотели сказать "без оператора группировки". Без него будет неяная группировка по всем  записям ([тут я описывал подробней](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/975615)).

Comment: Да, я видел уже, наверное, проще тупо поставить ссылку на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Можно и ссыллку, или  так переформулироать "... без group by вернёт одну строку с  результатом функции, в данном случае число строк или 0, если ни одной не найдено", или что-то в этом духе.

Comment: Собственно, ссылку то уже и не надо, она из комментария уже в связаные  попала. Вы как автор решаете, улучшать или нет. В остальном, полностью овечает на вопрос ТС (плюс).