# Запрос с оператором AND и пустой строкой в условии выборки

Tags: sql, oracle

Делаю запрос к таблице таким образом:

```
select roomid from roomname where description='Нефтяная лаборатория' and purpose='';
```

В колонке `purpose` пусто, так лежат данные в БД. И почему-то я получаю пустой запрос, а должен по логике получить ID записи. Если обе колонки содержат данные, тогда запрос выполняется, ну а когда поле пустое это же тоже данные вроде бы.

Или я как-то не так сделал запрос?

Comment: Только так `and purpose is null`.

Comment: @Mike там именно null

Comment: @Mike Это оракл, у них пусто не бывает.

Comment: Да спасибо , с nullom заработало

Comment: @0xdb Офигеть. Не знал. даже проверил сейчас ... Спасибо

Comment: @Mike Так "исторически сложилось". По ссылке в ответе, я разглагольствую-разглагольствую, а никто не читает :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Надо так: `... and purpose is null`.

---

*Oracle*, в отличае от других *СУБД*, не делает пока различий между пустой строкой и `NULL`.

```
select '' value, length ('') len from dual;
```

Такой запрос, вместо ожидаемых `''` (пусто) и `0`, вернёт:

```
VALUE        LEN
----- ----------
null  null
```

Поэтому, сравнение с пустой строкой - `purpose=''`, равнозначно - `purpose=NULL`,
что в результате всегда **false**.

Подробнее, почему так вышло, и содержит ли пустая строка данные, [в этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/805114/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-varchar-%d0%b8-varchar2/807270#807270).