# Как добавить пустую строку в JSON_OBJECT_T объект?

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, oracle18c

Пробую добавить пустую строку к сушности типа `JSON_OBJECT_T`, но как результат получаю значение `null`, а не пустую строку.

```
DECLARE
   V_OBJ JSON_OBJECT_T;
BEGIN
   V_OBJ := JSON_OBJECT_T();
   V_OBJ.PUT('customerAccRef','');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_OBJ.stringify);
END;
```

Результат работы кода выше, следующий JSON:

```
{"customerAccRef":null}
```

, но желаемый результат такой:

```
{"customerAccRef":""}
```

Может кто-то подсказать, что надо изменить, чтобы получить пустую строку?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to put empty string in JSON_OBJECT_T object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55516163) от участника [@Kinjan Bhavsar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4431703/kinjan-bhavsar)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/55516163

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо за правку! Выделять кодом в загаловке не получится, обратные кавычки так и остаются сами собой.

Answer (score 2):

Причина такого поведения, потому что Oracle иннерпретирует пустую строку как `NULL`.

Так исторически сложилось, что поведение пустой строки отличается от стандарта SQL, и можно [почитать в этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/203536/7998591), чтобы ознакомиться с этим более подробно.
<sub>Прим.ред.: на SO по русски можно найти аналогичную информацию в [этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/985023), [или в этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/805114) с укороченным переводом ответа выше.</sub>

Сам я не смог найти нигде в документации по JSON объектам, описания, как обойти эту проблему. Был бы рад, если бы кто-нибудь смог подсказать, где её можно найти.

В качестве пути решения, можно использовать функцию `TRIM` для преобразования одного пробела в пустую строку, вот так:

```
V_OBJ.PUT('customerAccRef' , TRIM(' '));
```

Что даст:

```
{"customerAccRef":""}
```

Похоже, это работает как в версии 12.2, тестировал на локальной машине, так и в 18c [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=46df35ce86ba87d566d029628ea875dd), а также в 19c [LiveSQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/h685vtb35l67w5gpwe9v3noie).

Здесь следует заметить, что запрос `select TRIM(' ') from dual` всегда возвращает `NULL`. Это удивительно, почему он работает как ожидалось с JSON объектами.

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55518719) от участника [@Kaushik Nayak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7998591/kaushik-nayak)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Для лучшей читаемости, предложил бы как решение квотированный литерал, как то так:

```
var jsonObject varchar2 (32)
declare 
    jo json_object_t := json_object_t();
begin 
    jo.put ('abc', q'""');
    :jsonObject := jo.stringify ();
end;
/

JSONOBJECT
----------
{"abc":""}
```

---

Две одиночные кавычки `''` это символьный литерал и его значение - пустая строка, а не `NULL`. Расхождение со стандартом SQL начинается при присвоении символьного литерала переменной или колонке с конкретным типом данных.

Выше упомянут стандарт SQL, но PL/SQL это не SQL и поведение может отличаться. Например, обе переменные имеют значение `NULL`, но как параметры для встроенных функций БД они интерпретируются по разному:

```
var ret varchar2 (64)
declare 
    jo json_object_t := json_object_t();
    nullstr  varchar2(1) := null; 
    zerostr varchar2(1) := ''; 
begin 
    jo.put ('foo', nullstr);
    jo.put ('bar', zerostr);
    :ret := jo.stringify ()||' # >>'||nullstr||zerostr||'<< '|| 
        case when nullstr is null and zerostr is null then 'both values are null' end;
end;
/

RET
-------------------------------------------------
{"foo":null,"bar":""} # >><< both values are null
```

Это отличие в поведении пока не документированно.
В SQL, напротив, литерал с пустой строкой при присвоении становится `NULL`, никаких отличий в поведении нет:

```
select 
    json_object ('foo' value q'""') jo1, 
    json_object ('bar' value trim (' ')) jo2, 
    json_object ('baz' value cast ('' as varchar2(1))) jo3 
from dual
/

JO1              JO2              JO3             
---------------- ---------------- ----------------
{"foo":null}     {"bar":null}     {"baz":null}
```