# Как сделать так, чтобы LISTAGG учитывала NULL значения?

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица `TABLE1` с такими данными:

```
+------------+
|    COL1    |
+------------+
|   FOO      |
|   BAR      |
|  (null)    |
|   EXP      |
+------------+
```

Если выполняю:

```
SELECT listagg(col1, '#') within group(ORDER BY rownum) 
  FROM table1;

COLLIST
----------------
FOO#BAR#EXP
```

Функция `LISTAGG` игнорировала `NULL` значения, но хотел бы их учесть, т.е. получить: `FOO#BAR##EXP`.

Как можно этого достичь, чтобы не писать свою функцию?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Oracle 11g: LISTAGG ignores NULL values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17697475) от участника [@WBAR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320104/wbar)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/17697475

Comment: Все проблемы от того, что с точки зрения Оракла пустая строка - это, блин, тоже NULL...

Comment: а `case` не поможет при такой проблеме?

Comment: @PotroNik А чем оно поможет? Я ж говорю - пустая строка с точки зрения Оракла - тоже NULL. И при этом сложение числа с NULL даёт NULL, а сложение (конкатенация) строки - эту строку, а ни фига не NULL... ну не бред, а? не. можно изобресть какую-нить дурь типа `REPLACE(LISTAGG(COALESCE(column, CHR(0)), '#'), CHR(0), '')` - но только чем оно лучше-то?

Comment: @Akina,теперь мне более понятно, спасибо за пояснение! "Интересное" поведение Null конечно.

Comment: @PotroNik Пдробнее о  "пустой строке" было [в этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/807270/217579).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вся проблема - из того, что Oracle не различает пустую строку и NULL, для него это одно и то же (причём с числовыми типами ничего подобного нет). Поэтому простое и очевидное

```
SELECT listagg(COALESCE(col1, ''), '#') within group(ORDER BY rownum) 
  FROM table1;
```

сработает где угодно - но не в Oracle.

Возможный выход - замена NULL на строковый литерал, который гарантированно отсутствует в значениях. В 99% случаев в качестве такого литерала я предпочитаю использовать `CHR(0)`. После замены агрегирование будет выполнено нормально, без игнорирования NULL, а после агрегирования нужно выполнить обратную замену. Т.е.

```
SELECT REPLACE(listagg(COALESCE(col1,CHR(0)), '#') within group(ORDER BY rownum), CHR(0), '') 
  FROM table1;
```

Если же агрегируемое поле имеет бинарный тип (RAW/LOB), то задача выбора правильного "заменителя NULL" усложняется... впрочем, о данных что-нибудь, да известно, так что возможный заменитель (который не обязан быть, кстати, однобайтовым) вполне можно предсказать. Да и необходимость подобной конкатенации для бинарных данных - вещь весьма сомнительная.

Comment: А вот это зачем: `ORDER BY rownum`?

Comment: @0xdb Оно есть в исходном запросе вопроса. Не вижу никаких оснований вносить изменения в этом моменте.

Comment: Эта сортировка просто безсмысленна.  Думаю, не стоит ее "рекламировать" в ответе.

Comment: @0xdb Если сортировка есть в вопросе - значит, она зачем-то нужна. Если её убрать, то результат изменяется.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3fccc6b32ac8488bf0367ae6aabff5b5 В этих условиях говорить, что она "бессмысленна" несколько безответственно. В мире форматов достаточно много форматов позиционно-зависимых.

Comment: Хорошо, посмотрю на досуге. Насколько помню,  это был баг в 11g, может и ошибаюсь.

Comment: @0xdb Если на другой версии не влияет - сделай `COL1` первичным индексом... *Насколько помню, это был баг в 11g* Крайне сомнительно. Как известно, сервер имеет право выполнять запрос так, как посчитает оптимальным. В том числе имеет право как угодно сортировать, если порядок сортировки не указан явно (впрочем, даже если сортировка указана явно, это не означает, что посередь выполнения не будет сортировки в ином порядке).

Comment: Совершенно верно, про это же и написал в первом комментарии. Если  сортировать, то явно - `order by col1`,  а не по `rownum`, которая по сути представляет собой номер записи в результате отсортированном случайным образом или неотсортированном вообще.

Comment: @0xdb Иными словами, `order by rownum`  и `order by null` есть по сути одно и то же - инструкция серверу не изменять порядка следования записей, стихийно сложившегося в ходе выполнения запроса, верно?

Comment: Ну да, верно, это одно и тоже. Единственное отличие - с rownum оптимизатор не распознаёт "сортировать не надо" и включает шаг сортировки, который не меняет ранее полученный порядок записей. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d7f30cde069ba72b455f1ddf72db9014) .

Answer (score 3):

Самое простое, добавить разделитель к самому значению:

```
select rtrim (listagg (col1||'#~') within group (order by null), '#~') collist 
from table1
/

COLLIST
------------------------
FOO#~BAR#~#~EXP
```

Возможно также с `XMLAGG`. Хотя на больших сетах данных будет не так эффективно, но не будет ограничения на макс. длину символьной строки:

```
select rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e, col1, '#~'))
    .extract ('//text()').getClobVal (), '#~') collist 
from table1
/

COLLIST
------------------------
FOO#~BAR#~#~EXP
```

Comment: Что означает `order by null`? И почему разделитель не такой как в вопросе?

Comment: @defaultlocale *Самое простое, добавить разделитель к самому значению* Ага... и молиться, чтобы последнее значение в листе не оканчивалось этим самым разделителем. Ведь постановка задачи никак не ограничивает на предмет наличия разделителя в агрегируемых значениях.

Comment: @Akina Дельное замечание, только это наверное автору ответа. Справедливости ради, если разделитель встречается в значениях, то это плохой разделитель и в таком случае надо уточнять требования.

Comment: @defaultlocale *если разделитель встречается в значениях, то это плохой разделитель* Я бы не был столь категоричен... почему не допустить, скажем, что агрегируемые значения сами по себе агрегаты?

Comment: @Akina Хороший пример, не подумал об этом.

Comment: @defaultlocale _Что означает order by null?_, означает, что сортировать не надо.

Comment: @Akina _если разделитель встречается в значениях [...]_, это хороший вопрос. Задайте его как новый вопрос, или дайте ещё один ответ.